# KEDA integrate with AWS MSK

Tags: aws-msk, keda

I am using AWS MSK, is it possible to integrate with Keda? I could not find any relevant documentation for AWS MSK.

Answer (score 0):

What do you exactly mean by integrate with AWS MSK? What do you want to scale? Cluster or Consumers?

In case you want to scale the cluster, the answer is **no**. That's not what Keda is meant for.

On the contrary, if you want to scale consumers, than the answer is **yes**, as MSK is just a managed (by AWS) Kafka cluster and it already exists a Kafka trigger (aka Scaler) for that whose description is [here](https://keda.sh/scalers/apache-kafka/). That's based on **consumer lag** metric.
After having deployed your consumer onto Kubernetes, all you have to do is apply a ScaledObject (Custom Resource), e.g.

```
apiVersion: keda.k8s.io/v1alpha1
kind: ScaledObject
metadata:
  name: kafka-scaledobject
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    deploymentName: myDeployment # the consumer deployment you want to scale
  pollingInterval: 30
  triggers:
  - type: kafka
    metadata:
      bootstrapServers: localhost:9092
      consumerGroup: my-group       # Make sure that this consumer group name is the same one as the one that is consuming topics
      topic: test-topic
      # Optional
      lagThreshold: "50"
```

Hope I helped.

Comment: I definitely want to scale Consumer & not the kafka itself. The problem I am facing is we have setup MSK with TLS encrypted without username & password. Where as in Keda for TSL username & password is compulsory , I am not able to configure MSK SSL with Keda

Comment: What about setting `authMode` with `none`? In that case username and password are not supposed to be mandatory... and you can still use other parameters for TLS encryption.

Comment: Did you guys make it work ?